# Unable to skip a line from Excel while doing copy activity in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a excel Column as a source in Copy Activity. I need to map the columns from source to sink (MS SQL Server).

I have one constraint, whenever I have a blank row in the excel source I should Stop the copy Activity.

I want to copy all the column data before the blank row, and ignore what ever after the blank row.

For example if I have this dataset:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF |
| HIJ | KLM |
|  |  |
| NOP | QRS |

Then the first two rows should be imported and the last two rows should not be imported.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ADF pipeline there are limited options for working with the contents of datasets (you can add cols, remove cols, etc) but modifying the rows themselves is hard. You can do it with dataflows but as your sink is mssqlserver then you can use row_number() to find any empty rows and keep the rows up to the blank row.

The process is:

- Create a staging table which is the same as the target table but includes a row column that is defined `row INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`
- Truncate the staging table
- Write the data to a staging table
- From the staging table write to the main table using the insert query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM staging_table 
  WHERE rowid < 
    (SELECT 
       COALESCE(MIN(rowid), (SELECT MAX(rowid)+1 FROM staging_table)) FROM staging_table WHERE a IS NULL)
```

Comment: rownumber is not fixed ,so how cani get the rownumber(means everytime i am getting diffrent data as input excel,also I cannot use dataflows since i our organisation not allows use azure ir

Comment: Can u suggest someother ways

Comment: I didnt used azure functions till now

Comment: what is your sink (destination)? is it a database? what type of database? @Being-Real

Comment: it is sql server

Comment: oh cool - then create a staging table, truncate it before you insert into it - include a row column `row IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL  INT` - then insert into that, then `insert into real_table select columns from staging_table where row < (select row from staging_table where col_ is null)`

Comment: Thanks That was clear for me .